# Пожалуйста, ответьте кто знает.. Сложные предложения

Tags: синтаксис

при помощи чего выражается зависимость придаточного предложения от главного?

А) при помощи членов предложения
б) при помощи союзов и союзных слов
в) при помощи вопросов
д) при помощи запятой
е) при помощи других знаков препинания

Answer (score 2):

При помощи союзов и союзных слов